# will , will be vs will get

Tags: passive-voice, idiomatic-language

Of the below sentences, which sentence is grammatically correct.

When do we use which of the below sentence?

> - If we can't leave by 4 o clock then our 1 hour is going **to** waste.
> - if we can't leave by 4 o clock then our 1 hour is going to **be** wasted.
> - if we can't leave by 4 o clock then our 1 hour is going to **get** wasted.

---

(Edit) From the comments, OP is trying to say that, since "peak hour traffic on the road will increase if we don't leave by certain time", some time is going to be wasted.  Is there a better way to express this in natural, idiomatic English?  Also, is there a way to express it naturally using the passive voice?

Comment: None are correct.  The sentence doesn't make much sense.  Why would you have wasted an hour if you don't leave by a certain time?

Comment: That is because the peak hour traffic on the road will increase if we don't leave by certain time.

Comment: Using your example sentence, would this meaning be obvious to the listener in your own native language?  In English "wasted time" doesn't include the meaning "sitting around in traffic", but in your own language it might.

Comment: what alternative we could use in English for the same?

Comment: That's a good question to ask here.  Let me edit this question and then see if we can reopen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To waste time" means to spend some amount of time in useless or frivolous activity.

> After he got home **he wasted an hour** watching TV before starting his homework.

In your example the activity is neither useless nor frivolous.  Rather, it just *takes more time than expected*.

> If we don't leave by 4 pm it will **take us an extra hour** to get there, because of the traffic.

This is, of course, based on opinion.  If you have something important to do at the destination, then you might feel time spent in traffic is *wasted*:

> ..., we will **waste an hour just sitting in traffic**.

You can also state this from the perspective of some future condition:

> ..., by the time we get there, we **will have wasted** an hour just sitting in traffic

You can also "spend time" doing something, similar to "take time" but indicating a more passive use of the time.

> ..., we **are going to spend** an extra hour in traffic.

This expression would not normally be expressed with the passive voice, and I don't see how to do it with "take time".  But it is possible with "waste" or "spend":

> If we don't leave by 4 pm, an hour **will have been wasted** by the time we get there.
>
> If we don't leave by 4 pm, an hour **will have been spent** sitting in traffic.